# how to speed up ansible template module?

Tags: ansible

The ansible template module is very slow in recent versions (It seems way faster before). For example I have 2 completely empty file `test1.sh` and `test2.sh`:

```
- name: Install script to /tmp
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
    mode: "u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx"
    unsafe_writes: true
  loop:
    - test1.sh
    - test2.sh
```

With `ANSIBLE_PIPELINING=1`, this simple task itself took 15 seconds. loop 10 files takes 80 seconds. This is unbelievably slow. The latency to the remote is actually very low << 100ms. Why is it so slow? What the ansible is doing during that time? Is there anyway to speed it up?

#### update

The actual problem is the recent ansible changed config file schema, which results in the ssh persist-connection mode been disabled.

Comment: If you can demonstrate an actual difference in speed between a recent version of Ansible and an earlier version of Ansible, you should [file a bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.yml), including the specific steps you used to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Set ``ANSIBLE_DEBUG=true``.You'll see in detail what's going on. The second column is the [UNIX epoch time](https://www.epochconverter.com/) of each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is the recent ansible changed config file schema, which results in that the ssh persist-connection mode had been disabled. Fix the .ansible.cfg make the ansible speed up to 3x